# Unable to create POJO with Retrofit and Java in android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, pojo

I am getting following json response from one of the vendor.

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
  "values": [
      [
        "2015-12-28T09:15:00+0530",
        1386.4,
        1388,
        1381.05,
        1385.1,
        788
      ],
      [
        "2015-12-28T09:15:00+0530",
        1386.4,
        1388,
        1381.05,
        1385.1,
        788
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to convert this to POJO.

I am using retrofit 2.0, rx java.

I have tried following

```
public class HistoricalDataContainer implements Parcelable{
public String status;
public CandleList data;

protected HistoricalDataContainer(Parcel in) {
    status = in.readString();
    data = in.readParcelable(CandleList.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(status);
    dest.writeParcelable(data, flags);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<HistoricalDataContainer> CREATOR = new Creator<HistoricalDataContainer>() {
    @Override
    public HistoricalDataContainer createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new HistoricalDataContainer(in);
    }

    @Override
    public HistoricalDataContainer[] newArray(int size) {
        return new HistoricalDataContainer[size];
    }
};
}
```

And

```
public class CandleList implements Parcelable{
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> values = new ArrayList<>();// doesn't work
public ArrayList<String[]> values=new ArrayList<String[]>();// doesn't work
public ArrayList<String>[] values; // doesn't work

protected CandleList(Parcel in) {
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<CandleList> CREATOR = new Creator<CandleList>() {
    @Override
    public CandleList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new CandleList(in);
    }

    @Override
    public CandleList[] newArray(int size) {
        return new CandleList[size];
    }
};
}
```

But in the above code "value" is always null.
What am I missing.

Comment: Did you implement the Retrofit CallBacks?

Comment: Oh yeah, every else else works fine, all other request, response and processing of them, except this.

Comment: What exactly did you receive in the response? Can you put here the message. There is some errors?. Always you can see if you debug the CallBack if the response code are right and what information. Can you share that?

Comment: The above posted one is the response i am getting. Null pointer exception. It says "values" is null.

Comment: Yes I read that but I was talking about your CallBack implementation and the response.body() and also check the response.code() there is where you know what really Retrofit receive.

Comment: you can http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ which generate pojo's for you json

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the annotations style for Gson.
For example:

```
public class LiveStreamResponse extends BaseResponse{
  @SerializedName("live_stream")
  @Expose
  private LiveStream liveStream;
  @SerializedName("meta")
  @Expose
  private Meta meta;

  public LiveStream getLiveStream() {
    return liveStream;
  }

  public void setLiveStream(LiveStream liveStream) {
    this.liveStream = liveStream;
  }

  public Meta getMeta() {
    return meta;
  }

  public void setMeta(Meta meta) {
    this.meta = meta;
  }
}
```

That help Retrofit to match with all objects on your POJO, you have to define which object have to be matched with your "status": "success", "data", "values" from the Json File.
You can read more about following this tutorial. [Consuming APIs with Retrofit](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit)

And also I give you this example [using xml and Json](https://github.com/williamgdev/Retrofit/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/gthub/williamg/myapplication).

Comment: Not necessarily, if the variable name and json key are same, this works. But only in case, for example, we receive email_id as json key, and we use emailID as variable, in that case we have to use @SerializedName. Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to identify the objects that are in the JSON structure, in this case there are two.1. The json that you are receiving and 2. `data` .
The option is to create a class for every object.

the first class contains the main object (json itself) with his main attributes: `status` and `data`.

```
public class HistoricalDataContainer implements Parcelable {
    private string status;
    private Data data;
    setters - getters
    ...
}
```

**data** is an object, so you need to create his own class to handle his attributes, in this case is an array with string arrays

```
    public class Data implements Parcelable {
            private List<String> values;
            setters - getters
            ...
        }
```

To get an specific array inside values you are going to do something like:

```
List<String> myStringArray = historicalDataContainer.getData().values().get(index);
```

AND

**Why are you using `Parcelable`?**

...
I hope this answer is what you need!

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for JSON Mapping. It's a great tool for creating models from existing JSON responses. And for quick implementation of Parcelable to existing class you can use http://www.parcelabler.com/

Comment: Tried that too, not working :). Thanks for the suggestion though.